# MFC, Memory Leak при передаче параметров в поток

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mfc, утечка-памяти

День добрый.
Уже полтора дня пытаюсь разобраться в причинах сообщений об утечках памяти(Memory Leaks Detected...) в OutPut'е проекта. И за эти полтора дня мне удалось выяснить, что утечки связаны с потоком и передачей ему параметров.

Программа выглядит примерно так:
Диалоговое окно -> На нём размещён CTabCtrl -> Окно, которое активируется, когда открыта определённая вкладка.

В NewTabDlg.h объявлена структура и переменные:

```
HANDLE hListScan;
CWinThread* cwListScan;
CListCtrl ItemList;
CButton ScanEnabled;
typedef struct SData{
    CButton* Button;
    CListCtrl* List;
}SDataTrans;
```

В NewTabDlg.cpp, при изменении значения CheckBox'а создаётся поток:

```
void NewDialog::OnBnClickedCheckscan(){
    SDataTrans *data = new SDataTrans;
    data->Button = &ScanEnabled;
    data->List = &ItemList;
    if (ScanEnabled.GetCheck() > 0){
        cwListScan = AfxBeginThread(&ListScanThread, (LPVOID)data, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(cwListScan->m_hThread)
            hListScan = cwListScan->m_hThread;
    }
}
```

И сама функция потока:

```
UINT ListScanThread(LPVOID pParam) {

    SDataTrans * data = (SDataTrans *)pParam;

    while (data->Button->GetCheck() > 0) {

        CString strBuffer;

        for (int i(0); i <= MAX_ITEMS; i++) {
            if (lstrcmp(data->List->GetItemText(i, 0), SProd[i].Name) != 0)
                data->List->SetItemText(i, 0, SProd[i].Name);
            strBuffer.Format(_T("%i"), SProd[i].iPrice);
            if (lstrcmp(data->List->GetItemText(i, 1), strBuffer) != 0)
                data->List->SetItemText(i, 1, strBuffer);
            strBuffer.Format(_T("%i"), SProd[i].iAmount);
            if (lstrcmp(data->List->GetItemText(i, 2), strBuffer) != 0)
                data->List->SetItemText(i, 2, strBuffer);
        }
        Sleep(300);
    };

    data->List->DeleteAllItems();

    delete data;
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно, варианты развития событий.

1. Во время работы программы, если совсем не трогаешь CheckBox, поток не
   запускается и, соответственно, при закрытии приложения нет утечек.
2. Если запустить поток, активировав CheckBox и закрыть программу не сняв галочку с CheckBox'а, появляются сообщения об утечке памяти "{1025} client block at 0x01AE6328, subtype c0, 68 bytes long.", "atlTraceGeneral - a CWinThread object at $01AE6328, 68 bytes long". Но, если в OnClose() родительского окна прописать:
   NewTabDlg.ScanEnabled.SetCheck(0);
   WaitForSingleObject(NewTabDlg.hListScan, INFINITE);
   OnDestroy();
   То поток, судя по нагрузке не работает(т.е. ничего не делает), но и программа зависает и находится в ожидании и не завершается.
3. Во время работы программы, играемся с CheckBox'ом, включаем/выключаем и поток за потоком успешно завершают. Убираем галочку с CheckBox'а и закрываем программу. -> Получаем кучу сообщений об утечке памяти, и чем больше раз включали/выключали, тем больше этих сообщений.

Собственно, даже предположить не могу из-за чего это происходит. Уже много чего перепробовал.

Comment: В общем, удалось выяснить при каких конкретно обстоятельствах происходит утечка, но как это решить... Утечка происходит при передаче параметра в поток, в данном случае структуры. Всё из-за неё. Хоть она и удаляется в конце потока, появляется утечка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Данный тред - яркий пример человеческой невнимательности, а именно - моей.

В функции, из которой открывался поток, не удалялась структура.
В общем, правильно это выглядит так:

```
void NewDialog::OnBnClickedCheckscan(){
    SDataTrans *data = new SDataTrans;
    data->Button = &ScanEnabled;
    data->List = &ItemList;
    if (ScanEnabled.GetCheck() > 0){
        cwListScan = AfxBeginThread(&ListScanThread, (LPVOID)data, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(cwListScan->m_hThread)
            hListScan = cwListScan->m_hThread;
    }
    else { delete data; } // удаляем data
}
```

Comment: Странное решение. А почему вы тогда вообще сначала создаете эту структуру, а только потом проверяете, нужна ли она? Почему бы не сделать проверку `ScanEnabled.GetCheck() > 0` *сначала*, а уж только потом делать `new SDataTrans`. А то, что у вас получилось сейчас, выглядит как попытка подавить баг антибагом.

Answer (score 1):

Так а где у вас в коде уничтожается объект `CWinThread`, указуемый `cwListScan`? Этот объект создается динамически внутри `AfxBeginThread`

```
CWinThread* AFXAPI AfxBeginThread(AFX_THREADPROC pfnThreadProc, LPVOID pParam,
    int nPriority, UINT nStackSize, DWORD dwCreateFlags,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttrs)
{
  ...
  CWinThread* pThread = DEBUG_NEW CWinThread(pfnThreadProc, pParam);
  ...
  return pThread;
}
```

Он обычно освобождается внутри `AfxEndThread`, вызываемого в конце потока

```
void AFXAPI AfxEndThread(UINT nExitCode, BOOL bDelete /* = TRUE */)
{
  AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE* pState = AfxGetModuleThreadState();
  CWinThread* pThread = pState->m_pCurrentWinThread;
  ...
  if (bDelete)
    pThread->Delete();
  ...
}
```

У вас же вызова `AfxEndThread` нигде не видно.

Если вы не хотите вызвать `AfxEndThread`, то делать `delete cwListScan` - это ваша обязанность.

Код, конечно, ужасен и в других отношениях, но тем не менее есть немалая вероятность, что ваши memory leaks - это в том числе именно оно.

Comment: Всё верно, упустил данную строку кода, надо было сразу её вставить. Но в данном случае проблемы утечки это не решает. Утечки, которые описаны в 3-ем пункте всё также остаются. Ещё интересный момент, что при закрытии программы в то время, пока поток ещё активен, он никак не хочет завершаться сам. И в таких случаях даже при прописанном AfxEndThread ко мне возвращается утечка из 2-о пункта.